# How to escape the ampersand in "$quote;"

Tags: javascript, jsp, kendo-ui

I use a kendo template in jsp:

```
<assd:column has-tooltip="false" width="150px" name="groupName"
                             template="<span data-link-value='{gId:&quot;#:id#&quot;, gName:&quot;#:schoolNameSafe# группа #:groupNameSafe# (#:groupType#)&quot;, gType:&quot;#:groupTypeId#&quot;, imported:&quot;#:hasLicenses#&quot;}'>#:groupName#</span>"
                >Group</assd:column>
```

And also a JavaScript logic like:

```
var template = kendo.template(this.rowLinkTemplate);
var fieldData = {};

var dataLinkValue = $("[data-link-value]", arg.currentTarget).attr("data-link-value");
var link = template(eval("(" + dataLinkValue + ")"));
document.location = link;
```

I have an input string for *gName*: "CDS "Car Driving School""

The problem is in ampersand in **$quot;** which is perceived by browser as a delimiter and it turns out that ***CDS*** goes to the gName variable, but everything after is considered a key because of the ampersand.

Is it possible to escape the ampersand in **$quot;**?

Comment: Using eval() on something the end user can change ( like the data value of a span element ) is never a good idea. Is there a way you could just create that template string a different way, one that also avoids the quotes issue, like a function returning the string? Or a template literal using backticks? `

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you couldn't just use " normally and escape it (rather than encode it)? e.g.

```
<assd:column has-tooltip="false" width="150px" name="groupName"
    template="<span data-link-value='{gId:\"#:id#\", gName:\"#:schoolNameSafe# группа #:groupNameSafe# (#:groupType#)\", gType:\"#:groupTypeId#\", imported:\"#:hasLicenses#\"}'>#:groupName#</span>"
>Group</assd:column>
```

Disclaimer: I don't know much about kendo so it is entirely possible that there is a reason that this can't be done that I'm unaware of.